# OAuth2 Implementation

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

This is a bit of a theoretical question, however I'll try to be as detailed as possible. I've read a bunch of documentation on oath2/SSO implementation(I know they're not the same)- so I need to get beyond hand-wavy to actual system design. So here's what I think an Oauth2 implementation should look like.
The core design involves a bunch of micro services(which I'm calling app here) that all use the same authorization server.

To my understanding these are the end-points an auth server is supposed to provide.

> Authorization Server
>
> 1. End point for an app to register -> Once registered the app is provided a client Id and client secret(these are essentially permanent
>      and don't change.
> 2. Endpoint for an user to register -> This request should come with the client Id and client secret so that the authorization server can
>      associate an user with an app.
> 3. Endpoint for an user to login -> If the user is an authorized user then he/she is provided an access token.
> 4. Endpoint with user details -> If an authorized app(correct client ID and secret) makes a request with an authorized user(correct access
>      token) then an user blob is returned.
>
> Resource server(App)
>
> Now that the resource server has this basic user data it can
>   deserialize the JSON object into its own user class and then have
>   one-to-one mapping to things like user_address/user_location etc.

This is my understanding of Oauth2-SSO. I'd highly appreciate some help around the rough edges. TIA !!!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't implemented oath2 myself but the system I work on does use it, what you describe seems to be the same as what we use;

We initialize the client with an endpoint and the client secret and ID, then use our user's credentials to get a token (or an error message if the user/client credentials are invalid). From there we use the app's endpoints to call our applications. From what I can see our Oauth2 methods seem to do what you describe in your question, it should be correct.